# add bracket across numbers at only end of each line

Tags: regular-expression, vi

I have a file having lines as:

```
ram_reg_10/raja_reg_9/raghu_reg_8  
abc_reg_4/bcd_reg_5  
cad/pqr_reg_91
```

I want to convert string "_reg_number" into [number] at only last of every line in vi editor.
output should be:

```
ram_reg_10/raja_reg_9/raghu[8]  
abc_reg_4/bcd[5]  
cad/pqr[91]
```

I tried:

```
:%s?_reg_[0-9]$?\[[0-9]\]?g
```

But it gives:

```
ram_reg_10/raja_reg_9/raghu[[0-9]]  
abc_reg_4/bcd[[0-9]]  
cad/pqr_reg_91
```

how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In command mode:

```
:%s/_reg_\([0-9]\+\)$/[\1]/
```

Here we use `\+` to match one or more group of numbers at the end. So we don't have substitute with lines like `cad/pqr_reg_`.

Comment: Note this doesn't catch multiple digits, like for example `91`. For the rest, it is the same as my answer :)

Comment: Downvoting: for posting almost the same as me and updating on grace period what I mentioned without mentioning, which made the solution even more close to mine. Wouldn't expect such behaviour from a veteran user. Also, an explanation of the command would help.

Comment: @fedorqui: Please checking again, your solution is different with mine. You can add an entry like `cad/pqr_reg_`, then yours will provide the wrong answer.

Comment: Yes, that is true and now I notice. But your initial answer (before my comment) was something like `_reg_\([0-9]\)\+$`, (good idea, but not working). I didn't like the situation. Could you do a fake edit so that I can undownvote?

Comment: @fedorqui: Maybe it's a simple mistypo, vim regex syntax is incredible, and I still editting while you was seeing my answer. And I don't think voting is important, do what ever you want:)

Answer (score 0):

Just use this:

```
:%s/_reg_\([0-9]*\)$/[\1]/
```

That is, catch the number with `\(` and `\)` and then print it back with `\1`. Note also there is no need to `/g`, because you perform it just once per line.

Comment: reg_ should be _reg_ in your answer , BTW thanks :)

Comment: Ok now I see, @yogendrasingh . Updated.